# What does that mean of PgIn[ST3P], RdMeta[ST3UP] when use fs_usage in osx

Tags: macos

When i use "sudo fs_usage -w -f diskio" in terminal to show disk call status, the call column show something like this: PgIn[ST3P], PgIn[AT3UP], PgIn[S], PgIn[AT1], WrMeta[A], PgIn[AT3U], RdData[ANT3U], RdMeta[ST2], RdMeta[ST3UP], WrData[AT1], ...

What does that mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the fs_usage man page:

> CALL  The name of the network or filesystem related call, page-in, page-out, or physical disk access.

PgIn and PgOut are page-in and page-out.
RdMeta and WrMeta are reading and writing file metadata.
RdData and WrData are reading and writing to the file.

Comment: Thanks :) , and what is meaning about "AT1", "AT3UP" ...? Is there some document to describe them?

Comment: @aliasw I don’t know but perhaps someone else does, I guess internal references

Answer (score 0):

It's a shame that Apple don't seem to have documented all of the output.

This is the relevant source, I think: https://github.com/apple-open-source/macos/blob/master/system_cmds/fs_usage.tproj/fs_usage.c ... see the `diskio_print` function.

Another answer here describes `RdData`, `WrData` and so on.  There also seem to be related `CS` codes: eg `RdMetaCS`.

`[ST3P]`, `[AT3UP]`, `[S]`, `[AT1]` and so on are from the code below. I read this as:

- `A` or `S` = async / sync
- `N` = nocache
- `T` is optionally followed by a number: this is something to do with `P_DISKIO_TIER_MASK` and `P_DISKIO_TIER_SHIFT`... and then this is optionally followed by `U`, indicating `P_DISKIO_TIER_UPGRADE`
- `P` = passive

```
        buf[len++] = '[';

        if (type & P_DISKIO_ASYNC)
            buf[len++] = 'A';
        else
            buf[len++] = 'S';

        if (type & P_DISKIO_NOCACHE)
            buf[len++] = 'N';

        int tier = (type & P_DISKIO_TIER_MASK) >> P_DISKIO_TIER_SHIFT;

        if (tier > 0) {
            buf[len++] = 'T';
            if (tier > 0 && tier < 10)
                buf[len++] = '0' + tier;

            if (type & P_DISKIO_TIER_UPGRADE) {
                buf[len++] = 'U';
            }
        }

        if (type & P_DISKIO_PASSIVE)
            buf[len++] = 'P';

        buf[len++] = ']';
```